# Full width Vim help text

Tags: wrapping, help-system

Is it possible to view the help in Vim at a text width greater than 77 characters? Can Vim reflow the help text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "help page" is nothing more than a buffer with `filetype=help` and `nomodifiable` set.

You can make it modifiable with `:set modifiable`, and then edit it like you would any buffer, e.g. by setting the `textwidth` to what you like and using `gq` to re-format text.

If you would like to do this automatically, you can do something like:

```
augroup help
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype help
        \ set modifiable noreadonly textwidth=120
        \| normal! gqG
augroup end
```

However, a quick test reveals that this doesn't work very well for many help pages, so I wouldn't recommend doing this. You'll have to make a custom `formatprg` or `equalprg`.

Comment: That most likely won't work very well, because the Vim help files are written for terminal size windows. It might be easier to view the html vim documentation files with a text browser, which should be able to reflow for wider screens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Vim just displays a text file in a help window with proper highlighting. All help files are available at `$VIMRUNTIME/doc/` and they are already formatted with that width.